# How to send an e-mail after a job has finished?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I created an application that bundles multiple batch jobs. The user can start a job which is then placed in a queue. When the job has been finished I want to send a report to the user.

I know that there is the `JobExecutionListener` interface. I can implements the e-mail functionality in the `afterJob()` method. The next step would be to register this listener to my jobs.

Is there a way to do it automatically with all my jobs? I don't want to configure it for every new job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom `BeanPostProcessor` that adds the listener to the jobs:

```
@Component
public class MailListenerBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private MailListener listener;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof AbstractJob) {
            final AbstractJob job = (AbstractJob) bean;

            job.registerJobExecutionListener(listener);
        }

        return bean;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this...

```
public class CustomJobExecutionListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    public void beforeJob(JobExecution arg0) {
      // send email here
    }

    public void afterJob(JobExecution arg0) {
        ExitStatus exitStatus = arg0.getExitStatus();
        String code = exitStatus.getExitCode();
        // send email here
    }

}
```

XML config :-

```
<bean id="customJobExecutionListener" class="com.myBatch.CustomJobExecutionListener"/>

       <batch:job id="job1" restartable="true">
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="customJobExecutionListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
                ...
                ...
        </batch:job>
```

Comment: This does not answer my question, because the listener is not automatically registered on all my jobs. However, I already found a solution using a `BeanPostProcessor`.

Comment: Using <batch:listener> the respective listener could be registered to any job like how i have shown on the above xml sample.

Comment: Sure, but I would have to add this part to all my job configurations, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Ok i got your query and would say your resolution is good. I could think of another way of doing this with the help of PARENT attribute as :-                                                        <job abstract="true" id="parentJob">
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="customJobExecutionListener"/>
    <listeners>
</listeners></job>

<job id="job1" restartable="true" parent="parentJob">
    ...
    ...
 </job>